# Received a traffic violation notice in the mail

Tags: automobiles

I live in Illinois. I received a violation from Tollroads.com. I havent driven my car in the state of California. I was on a flight from Brussels to Chicago on the day of the violation.What should I do?

Comment: That isn't a real web site. What exactly did you receive?

Comment: Please post a scan of the document(s) you received, with your personal data blanked out. As Michael Hampton correctly observes, the URL is not assigned, so there's no actual website at that address. What you received is almost certainly seeking personal information from you via phishing.

Comment: Does the notice show a photograph of the vehicle and licence plate, and state it too? In the UK, ownership data is not in the public domain. There is also a possibility of mis-reading the plate. In the pre-tech days I received a real parking violation notice from a town I had never visited. After being stone-walled it turned out the offending car was a different colour, and even then they accused me of re-spraying it. It took sending a copy of the documents to get it cancelled.

Comment: Just how is this a travel question within the scope defined in the [help]?

Answer (score 6):

The official website of the California Toll Roads is https://thetollroads.com/ (note "the").  There you can verify if the notice is genuine, and if it is, there should be an option to appeal or contest it.

You should carefully check their information about the car involved in the violation; it could be a mistake, or (less likely) that somebody has a fake license plate that matches yours.  In the latter case you may also want to report it to the police.